# Insertar fecha actual en una tabla mysql - php

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

Tengo una duda con respecto a insertar la fecha actual en una fila en una tabla de mysql en caso de que no exista tal registro.
Ejemplo: que inserte 2017-10-10 en una fila si es que no existe. Pero que inserte un nuevo registro en caso de que sea otro dia como mañana ( 2017-10-11).
Habia leido algo con curdate () y el NOW (), pero no estoy seguro cual seria lo correcto o mas apropiado.

Comment: `CURDATE()` arroja la fecha sin la hora y `NOW()` fecha y hora

Comment: por favor puedes ser mas especifico a tu pregunta, por lo que dices es basada en opiniones

Answer (score 5):

Diferencia entre CURDATE() vs NOW()

[CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)  retorna la fecha actual en formato 'YYYY-MM-DD' o YYYYMMDD, dependiendo si la funcion es usado como cadena(string) o como numero ( numeric).

```
mysql> SELECT CURDATE();
        -> '2008-06-13'
mysql> SELECT CURDATE() + 0;
        -> 20080613
```

[NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) Retorna la fecha y hora actual en formato 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'  or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, dependiende si la funcion es usada como una cadena o como numero.

```
mysql> SELECT NOW();
        -> '2007-12-15 23:50:26'
mysql> SELECT NOW() + 0;
        -> 20071215235026.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Solo tienes que usar la función `NOW()` e insertará fecha y hora del momento.

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo1, campo2)
VALUES (NOW(), valor);
```